# Getting rows of coordinates from text file and checking whether points are inside polygon

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, shapely

I have hundreds of coordinates (control points) in a text file in the following order (x y):

```
5480.000 -4880.000
5480.000 -4860.000
5480.000 -4840.000
5480.000 -4820.000
5480.000 -4800.000
5480.000 -4780.000
5480.000 -4760.000
5480.000 -4740.000
5480.000 -4720.000
5480.000 -4700.000
```

and polygon's coordinates (12):

```
259.59 229.87
329.07 284.19
397.76 262.62
480.03 397.60
336.26 545.37
325.88 400.00
142.17 440.74
92.65 275.40
158.95 265.02
180.51 196.33
265.97 119.65
259.59 229.87
```

What I have to do is to check if control points are inside the polygon. Generaly I can do it if I have simple few coordinates in my script, but I have no idea how I can read tuples like this. I have a script that for now does not work.

It returns

```
File "C:/......../test.py", line 16, in <module> xc.append(row[0]) IndexError: list index out of range
```

Best solution would be if coordinates that are inside a polygon would appear in the Terminal.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import csv

poly = open(r"polygon.txt","r")
control = open(r"controlPoints.txt","r")

xp, yp = [], []
for l in poly:
    row = l.split()
    xp.append(row[0])
    yp.append(row[1])

xc,yc = [], []
for l in control:
    row = l.split()
    xc.append(row[0])
    yc.append(row[1])
print(xc)
print(yc)

# Create Point objects

p = Point(xc, yc)

# Create a Polygon 

coords = [xp, yp]
poly1 = Polygon(coords)
print(poly1)

# CHECK 

p.within(poly1)
print(p)

check=poly1.contains(p)
print(check)
```

Comment: What does "does not work mean?". What are you actually asking for help with?

Comment: Firstly, I would like my script to read coordinates from *.txt files - either control points or polygon coordinates. Finally, I would like to check which control points from file are inside the polygon and show those coordinates. My biggest problem is that script does not read coordinates at all now.

Comment: Now indentation is exactly like in my code. There is the following problem:
  `File "C:/......../test.py", line 16, in <module>
    xc.append(row[0])
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: **You have a typo in your code.** In your first for loop, you are appending both points to `xp`. Also don't name both your file object and your Polygon object as `poly`.

Comment: That error could appear when you have a blank line in your input file. Test `len(row) == 2` before appending that data. You may want to add a `strip()` to sanitize your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of list comprehension and [map()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map) to create the needed nested lists for shapely:

```
poly = Polygon([tuple(map(float, row.split())) for row in open(r"polygon.txt","r") if len(row.split()) == 2])
rawPoints = [tuple(map(float, row.split())) for row in open(r"controlPoints.txt","r") if len(row.split()) == 2]

for pt in rawPoints:
    p = Point(*pt)
    print (p, p.within(poly), poly.contains(p))
```

This prints:

```
POINT (5480 -4880) False False
POINT (5480 -4860) False False
POINT (5480 -4840) False False
POINT (5480 -4820) False False
POINT (5480 -4800) False False
POINT (5480 -4780) False False
POINT (5480 -4760) False False
POINT (5480 -4740) False False
POINT (5480 -4720) False False
POINT (5480 -4700) False False
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Anyway I have an error: `TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()` . What can be wrong with that?

Comment: It works, thank you so much!!! But what if I would like to count repeated conditions "True True" and print only those coordinates?